# SSRS - Grand Total of Group Expression Totals

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

My group total is an expression which subtracts the last `[Hours1]` value from the first `[Hours1]` value of the group `[EquipmentName1]` of the dataset "dataset1.

I need a Grand Total the group expression totals for each piece of equipment

I am unable to use the same formula of subtracting last [Hours1] value from the first [Hours1] value of the dataset "dataset1" because.

If I had 2 pieces of equipment, say Equipment1 and Equipment2:

```
Equipment1 last [Hours1] = 10000 and first [Hours1] = 9500
Equipment2 last [Hours1] = 10500 and first [Hours1] = 10000
```

If I used the formula of subtracting last `[Hours1]` value from the first `[Hours1]` value of the dataset `"dataset1"` the formula would be 10500 - 9500

However, I want:

```
(10000 - 9500) + (10500 - 10000) = Grand Total
```

Below is an attempt to draw part of my table

```
|_[Hours1]_|  =  Fields!Hours1.Value    
(e.g. 9500)

|___Expr___|  =  Last(Fields!Hours1.Value) - First(Fields!Hours1.Value) 
(e.g. 10000 - 9500 = 500)

|__________|  =  I need to total the value of Expr for all pieces of equipment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some custom code to achieve that.

Go to `Report -> Report Properties -> Code` and type

```
Dim grandTotal As Integer;
Function AccumulateTotal(value as Integer)
    grandTotal = grandTotal + value
    return value
End Function

Function GetTotal()
    return grandTotal
End Function
```

Then on the textboxes you need to call the accumulate function

```
=Code.AccumulateTotal(Last(Fields!Hours1.Value) - First(Fields!Hours1.Value))
```

And on the Grand Total textbox you call the get total function

```
=Code.GetTotal()
```

Comment: Caveat: This is not going to work in SSRS 2208 R2 in the Reports web viewer, since the grandTotal will be reset with every new page (I just tested it).

Comment: What I've also done in the past was using Group and Report Variables as well as hidden tables to store the totals.