# In an SSRS report, dividing the sum of one child group by the sum of another child group in a different parent group

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have a financial statement.  It has detail lines divided into the groups for Sales, Cost of Goods sold, Operating Expenses, and Other Expenses.

- Sales and Cost Of Goods Sold are in the parent Group "IF"
- Operating Expenses are in the parent group "E".

I want to divide the total of Operating Expenses by the total of Sales. Is that possible?

I've been struggling with this for a couple weeks. I was able to get the gross profit as a % of sales with this formula:

```
 = iif(Fields!SectionName.Value = "IF" and 
               Fields!Account_Type.Value = "I", 
                     (ReportItems!txtGP12.Value/Fields!Month12_Net.Value),"0").
```

Comment: Actually, that iif statement doesn't accomplish anything for me.  I get essentially the same result with this formula:  =ReportItems!txtGP12.Value/Fields!Month12_Net.Value

Comment: You can try doing some variation of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850524/ssrs-grand-total-of-group-expression-totals/12861881#12861881

Answer (score 0):

You can use in-built aggregate functions **and declare a scope** for which the aggregate should be performed. In your case you wish to `SUM()` sales, and `SUM()` operating expenses, *in the scope of the parent groups* you have.

#### Example

- For this example we will assume sales is in a field called **Sales** *in the data set*.
- Operating expenses is in a field called **Expenses** *in the data set*.
- Assume the same parent group names as you have described: **IF** and **E**
- The formula would be:

  `Sum(Fields!ExampleField.Value, "E") / Sum(Fields!ExampleField.Value, "IF")`

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not in separate fields.  It is the same field.  Sales and Expenses are only distinguished by their Account_Type attribute.

Comment: Updated for same field.

I'm assuming the field `Account_Type` is what the parent groups are being grouped on. If not, you may want to put up some more information about what the parent groups are being grouped on, as this will control how the `ExampleField` will be summed.